# Audio in HTML5 : how to play a sound after an other sound?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have three sound objects :

```
sound_a = new Audio("a.mp3");
sound_b = new Audio("b.mp3");
sound_c = new Audio("c.mp3");
```

I want to play the sound b when the sound a is finished. And play the sound c when the sound b is finish.

How I can do that ?

My code is the following :

```
sound_a.pause();
sound_a.currentTime = 0;
sound_a.play();

sound_b.pause();
sound_b.currentTime = 0;
sound_b.play();

sound_c.pause();
sound_c.currentTime = 0;
sound_c.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do it would be, keep a single audio object, array of sources, listen to end event and play:

```
let i = -1, sources =[...], a= new Audio(), playNext= e => {
  i++;
  if(!sources[i]) return;
  a.src=sources[i];
}
a.autoplay = true; 
a.onended = playNext;
playNext();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mido22/kr7ef7ny/1)

Comment: Thank you very much !!! 
how can I convert your code in normal mode ? (because you use 'strict')

Answer (score 1):

You can find an answer for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701346/how-can-i-queue-a-series-of-sound-html5-audio-sound-clips-to-play-in-sequence). If that does not help, try to find other solutions, since this question was already asked and solved before.